# Why does this Selenium test fail UNLESS I insert a pdb breakpoint?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, selenium

I have a Selenium LiveServerTestCase (django project) that tests an AJAXy page.  After the main page loads, there's a delay before another item loads, and I need to test for that second item. I'm trying to include a smart way to wait without doing `time.sleep(too_long)`, **but the test always fails unless I insert a pdb breakpoint.**

```
def some_test_thing(self):
    #loads a page with some ajaxy stuff, so there's a 
    #delay that needs to be accounted for
    url = "something..."
    self.browser.get(url)

    #import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace() #this test only passes with this statement, wtf^^?
    self.assertWithWait(self.assert_, args=(some_args,))
```

and I use the convenience function assertWithWait, which tries the assertion in a loop, catching the AssertionError if the test fails, until a timeout.

```
def assertWithWait(self, assertion, timeout=10, args=(), kwargs={}):
    total_time = 0
    while total_time < timeout:
        try:
            assertion(*args, **kwargs)
        except AssertionError:
            pass
        else:  # assertion passed
            return
        time.sleep(0.2)
        total_time += 0.2
    assertion(*args, **kwargs)  # final try, will cause test failure if unsuccessful
```

The problem is that the test always fails if I don't have that pdb breakpoint - the loop runs until the timeout at 10 seconds. However, if I include that pdb breakpoint, **and even if I enter "c" and continue immediately (like within 1 second), the test will pass**. So clearly it's not a timing issue, because the test completes successfully well within the 10 second timeout in the breakpoint case, but fails after waiting 10 seconds in the no-breakpoint case.  So it seems like something related to multiprocessing or multithreading that Selenium is doing, that maybe gets released by the pdb breakpoint?  I'm grabbing at straws a bit here.

Help!

**EDIT**
I'm using this assertWithWait not just to wait for things to load in the page, but to wait for the results of some AJAXy server calls to check that things changed in the database too.  So I can't just use Selenium's built-in WebDriverWait functions.  Sorry, should have been more clear about that.

Comment: If you want a better answer than the one you got already, you'll have to show more code in your question. In particular what it is that `self.assert_` does exactly.

Comment: self.assert_ is just an alias for self.assertTrue.  It's a unittest built in method

Comment: Ok, but you talked of checking the database in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DUH, my bad.  Objects!  Let's walk through the calling signature of assertWithWait and the way that assertion later gets executed, and the problem will become clear.  So here's the relevant stuff:

```
def assertWithWait(self, assertion, timeout=10, args=(), kwargs={}):
    ...
    assertion(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

Let's suppose the assertion is

```
self.assertEqual(SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1).some_field, 
                              "some value")
```

So we call `assertWithWait` like this:

```
self.assertWithWait(self.assertEqual,
    args=(SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1).some_field, 
          "some value"))
```

Can you spot my dumb mistake yet??

The args are being evaluated at the time that assertWithWait is called, and so at each iteration of the loop inside assertWithWait the **assertEqual is being called with exactly the same arguments (objects!)**.

The fix is to change the calling signature of assertWithWait to use lambda:

```
def assertWithWait(self, assertion_func, timeout=6):
    """
    Tries the assertion in a loop until a timeout.
    Usage:
    self.assertWithWait(lambda: assertion_statement)
    e.g.
    self.assertWithWait(lambda: self.assertEqual(something, something_else))
    """
    ...
    try:
        assertion_func()
    except AssertionError:
        pass
    ...
```

Now we have an all-purpose assertWithWait that can check browser elements OR database values (or whatever else you like).  And as a bonus, the calling syntax got easier to read - python ftw!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically *reinventing what an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) was made for*, use it and handle `TimeoutException`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def some_test_thing(self):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        self.fail("Element not found")
```

> This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if
>   it finds the element will return it in 0 - 10 seconds. WebDriverWait
>   by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it
>   returns successfully. A successful return is for ExpectedCondition
>   type is Boolean return true or not null return value for all other
>   ExpectedCondition types.

Comment: hmm... what about waiting for the result of an api call which POSTs, and I want to verify the object is now in my database?  That's more the use case the assertWithWait is for.  And this doesn't really explain why the existing code is not working.  Even though I may be partially reinventing some functionality... it should still work.

Comment: @andy well, yeah, the solution I've provided you with is selenium-specific - waiting for something happening in the browser, on a page. I've just spotted a pattern in your code which was so close to what I've read and know about explicit wait work, plus the question is tagged with `selenium`  - so, I've decided to let you know that there is smth in selenium that you can use. Thanks.